# How to display a list of links as a drop down select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, semantic-markup

I want to display a list of links like a drop down select, without losing the semantic if possible. Here's what I tried. The CSS obviously does not work now. For the select I emulated the link a bit with `location.href` in the JavaScript but it loses semantic value, and accessibility I guess.

Without jQuery and Bootstrap,

How to display a list of links as a drop down select ?

```js
document.getElementById("0").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  location.href = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
.like-select {
  appearance: select;
}
```

```html
<p>Semantic wanted</p>
<ul class="like-select">
  <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">Wikipedia</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.echojs.com/">Echo Js</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Look and feel wanted especially on mobile</p>
<select id="0">
  <option value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">Wikipedia</option>
  <option value="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</option>
  <option value="http://www.echojs.com/">Echo Js</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you want a dropdown of <a> tags?

Comment: yes but with the same native feel and look as `<select>` on mobile

Comment: I feel like you could attempt to mimic the look and feel of the native select box, but it would never be exact. Would that suffice?

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: yes, but it is even better without it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WAI provides multiple examples of emulated listbox using `role=listbox` and `role=option`. This requires the use of `aria-activedescendant` and `aria-selected` for better accessibility support.

[See Examples under section: 3.13 Listbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#Listbox)

For the styling, you can copy the [style used by the user agent stylesheet.](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L872)

That being said, it might a bad idea to style a list of links as a dropdown select as it could lead to an [unpredictable change of context](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html)

Comment: is the solution provided by LSKhan good from an accessibility perspective ?

Comment: @WalleCyril No keyboard support

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like this?Without using Jquery and Bootstrap solution

**Dropdown for Url**

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  Select URL...
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <ul class="like-select">
  <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">Wikipedia</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.echojs.com/">Echo Js</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
       width:160px;

    border: 1px solid;
}
.dropdown:after{
  content: '\25BC';
  position: relative;
    font-size:14px;
   float:right;


}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: inherit;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   top: 39px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
li a{
  text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    padding:10px;
}
ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
li{
      list-style: none;
    padding:10px;

  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
li:hover{
  background-color:gray;

}
li:hover a{
    color:white;
}
```

**JS**

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
var attribute;
var myFunction = function() {
attribute = this.getAttribute("data-target");
    var x = document.getElementById(attribute);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

};
for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/198bdcec/5/)

Comment: it works on desktop but on mobile there is no hover, only touch and swipe

Comment: Let me change it to click

Comment: ALL SOLUTION WITH JUST CSS AND HOVER ARE WORKING COMPLETLY WELL ON MOBILE!!! That comments that there is no hover on mobile are not quite right... The hover states are mapped to a finger tap and working on every mobile OS in every brwoser, have you ever tried!? I've developed dozens of navigations just with css, working completly fine on mobile! Normally the default behaviour already does the trick, in some cases you can make it more usable with some JS...

Comment: If you want a dropdown just with css and NO hover take a look at the "css checkbox hack" (just google that) and you'll find another quite good working solution! Maybe I'll post an answer with that approach...

Comment: this solution works perfectly only question is how do i add click out of the dropdown. i tried to click a random part of the screen but the dropdown is still up

Answer (score 4):

`<option>` does not take nested HTML elements.

What you have to do is style your `<ul> <li>` and make it look and feel like a native drop down.

Here is a working example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boxKRz

Comment: without jQuery or Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I made this sample only using CSS, hope this will help u

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="box">Hover Me
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown_item"><a href="http://thinkio.ca">111</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown_item"><a href="http://thinkio.ca">222</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
#box {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:default;
}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; /* change this value based on your browser */
    left: 10px;
}
ul li:hover>ul:last-child {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:rgb(33,144,255);
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

Link:
    https://codepen.io/zsydyc/pen/VMGGPv

Comment: Since the OP is tagged with accessibility, I’m assuming they care about users that navigate with the keyboard. Your example would need a fair bit of work to be keyboard accessible (being able to focus and navigate the options  with the keyboard.)

Comment: Does not behave like my `<select>` (wanted). Also `:hover` does not exist on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

ALL SOLUTION WITH JUST CSS AND HOVER ARE WORKING COMPLETLY WELL ON MOBILE!!! That comments that there is no hover on mobile are not quite right... The hover states are mapped to a finger tap and working on every mobile OS in every brwoser! Normally the default behaviour already does the trick, in some cases you can make it more usable with some JS...

If you want a dropdown just with css and NO hover here comes an other solution realized with a checkbox: (just google "css checkbox hack" for further information)

```css
.checkhack {
  display: none;
}

#menu {
  display: none;
}

#menutoggle:checked + #menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="menutoggle" class="checklabel">OPEN MENU</label>
<input id="menutoggle" class="checkhack" type="checkbox" />
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just add some select box a like styles and there it is mobile friendly as well... ;-)

Comment: Alternativly you could work with an anchor link and the :target-selector to  manage the toggle!

Comment: Yes you are right. I think there is misunderstanding, what I want to say is that on mobile the hover interaction does not exist because there is no mouse cursor standing still like on desktop. Now, some browser on mobile automatically translate hover into "touching" or "touched" and it works yes, but in this case why not directly use touchstart or click event. Also I gave an example in my question how I want it to feel and behave, and I don't think the `<select>` is opening on hover on desktop.

Comment: But my checkbox Solution above behaves exactly like a select or Not!? It does Not Open on hover but ob Click...

Answer (score 0):

quick way of making a combobox without using ID selector and keeping the HTML as above
link:https://codepen.io/gabep/pen/KXJoEK

first the CSS them the JS

fist I style the UL :

```
   .like-select {
  height:21px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:8%;
}

.like-select li{
  appearance: select;
color:red;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
   border-right: 1px solid blue;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

make the first child your box :

```
.like-select li:first-child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

make the last child the bottom part of dropdown:

```
 .like-select li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid blue;

    }
```

give the list item a hover effect :

```
.like-select li a:hover { 
  background-color: green !important;
}

.like-select li:first-child a:hover{ 
  background-color: none !important;
}

a {
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
}
```

now the Js:

```
    function load() {
  //add the main item to your list you need to have it in your drop-down:
```

// use querySelectorAll to find specific elements of any type and put in a list

```
  var addfirst= document.querySelectorAll(".like-select li:first-child");
    var ullist = document.querySelectorAll(".like-select"); 
   ullist[0].innerHTML =  addfirst[0].outerHTML + ullist[0].innerHTML ;


   y = document.querySelectorAll(".like-select li");

  // do an onlick here instead of mouse over
   y[0].onmouseenter = function(){

     //resize wrapper event - im not going to do a toggle because you get the idea 
var comboboxwrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".like-select");
comboboxwrapper[0].style.height = "100px";
 }


// loop though all other items except first-child
var i;
    for (i = 1; i < y.length; i++) { 
 y[i].onmouseover = function(){

   var selecteditem =document.querySelectorAll(".like-select li");
```

//change the value in the combobox with the value hovered over

```
  var mainitem = document.querySelectorAll(".like-select li:first-child");


  mainitem[0].innerHTML = this.innerHTML;   

 };


 } }

window.onload = load;
```